# Why doesn't the tick appear in my custom checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Can anyone explain why the tick does not appear when I check my custom checkbox and help me fix the issue? I attempted to replicate the example from W3Schools and here is my code:

```css
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

/* Hide the actual checkbox */
input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox*/
.checkbox::before {
  content: "";
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #737373;
}

.checkbox::after {
  content: "";
  border: 3px solid;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 10ms;
}

.checkbox input:checked ~ .checkbox::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="checkbox" style="margin-right: 3px;">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <span>Remember me</span>
  </div>
  <span>Need help?</span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a link to the thing you are trying to replicate? There are many examples. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: `.checkbox input:checked ~ .checkbox::after` <-- This selector won't work because the right-hand-side of `~` must be a _subsequent_ sibling. As it's 2023 now, consider using `:has()` instead.

Comment: L. Nelson yes that's exactly what i used lol. And thank you, Dai!

Answer (score 0):

You had a issue in the last block of your css, exactly here:

```
.checkbox input:checked ~ .checkbox::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

***Explanation:***

You were selecting an element by a class name `checkbox` using a precedence selector. The above css block meant: "Search for element with class `checkbox` and inside it search for an input element which is checked `:checked` and **then search for element with class `checkbox` which is available after the selected input which is set checked** or in other words **search for element with class `checkbox` which is preceded by input:checked element** but in your html you have no element after the input tag,hence it is not working. Also the `:after` and `:before` selectors overlaps the actual input checkbox hence you were not be able to click on it. This is solved by setting the `z-index` of both the selectors to -1.

The corrected code snippet is as follows:

```
<div class="bottom">
 <div class="left">
  <div class="checkbox" style="margin-right: 3px;">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <div class='customcheckbox'></div>
  </div>
  <span>Remember me</span>
 </div>
 <span>Need help?</span>
</div>
 
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

/* Hide the actual checkbox */
input[type=checkbox] {
  margin:0;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  opacity:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox*/
.customcheckbox::before {
  content: "";
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
  background-color: #737373;
}

.customcheckbox::after {
  content: "";
  border: 3px solid;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index:-1;
  transition: opacity 10ms;
}

.checkbox input:checked ~ .customcheckbox::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I hope I am clear with the explanation and the solution is working on your side as well. Cheers!

Comment: Great explanation but it didn't work lol. I changed the code a little bit by myself and it finally worked. Thank you for looking out anyway man, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is several errors in your code :

1. the "remember me" text should be in a label linked to the input or it won't be checked
2. if you hide completely the input, you should put it in display none, not opacity 0

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}
/* Hide the actual checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
label {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
/* Create a custom checkbox*/
.checkbox::before {
    content: "";
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #737373;
}
.checkbox::after {
    content: "";
    border: 3px solid;
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    width: 4px;
    height: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 10ms;
}
.checkbox:has(:checked)::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox" style="margin-right: 3px;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
    <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
</div>
```

Also, you should add javascript to trigger click on the input when clicking on the before

Comment: I changed my code a lil bit yesterday and the issue was solved. Thanks for the heads up anyway!